# Deleting Table Rows when Column 1 is Empty

Tags: excel, vba

My code is deleting all the `Table Rows` by the value/string of `Coulmn1`.

I have been using a Code which sometimes adds multiple numbers in the `Coulmn1` due to which more rows add to the `Table3` and sometimes add nothing whole `Coulmn1` is empty.

So this code manages the table accordingly and delete the additionally rows.

But when `Column1` is empty it deletes each row of the Table due to which all formulas have been removed from the table.

Now I just want to keep the First Row of the Table even if it is empty or not it should not be deleted in any condition by this I can keep my formulas.

```
Dim Rng1 As Range
On Error Resume Next
Set Rng1 = Range("Table3[[Order_No.]]").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks)
On Error GoTo 0
If Not Rng1 Is Nothing Then
Rng1.Delete Shift:=xlUp
```

Comment: Actually your question is pretty unclear because you didn't ask a question. What's wrong with your code? Do you get any errors? Please try to provide a [mcve] and explain what your issue is with what you have tried. • Actually I don't understand what the code you show has do do with what you explain in the text. Please also provide some example input and desired output data. Screenshots might help to give a good explanation.

Comment: Apologize that my question wasn't clear. Now i have edited and update the question.

Comment: Is your detection algorithm for when you want to delete working all right? If so - did you try Rng1.offset(1,0).Resize(Rng1.Rows.Count - 1, _ 
 Rng1.Columns.Count).delete shift:=xlUp ? See: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.range.resize

Comment: I tried to work with your way but its not working. Can you please post an answer. `Dim Rng1 As Range
Sheet6.Rng1.Offset(1, 0).Resize(Rng1.Rows.Count - 1, _
Sheet6.Rng1.Columns.Count).Delete shift:=xlUp`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I recommend to use the following syntax `ActiveSheet.ListObjects("Table3").ListColumns("Order_No.")` to work with list objects instead of `Range("Table3[[Order_No.]]")` because it gives you a way more options to access the data.

```
On Error Resume Next
With ActiveSheet.ListObjects("Table3").ListColumns("Order_No.").DataBodyRange
    Dim BlankCells As Range
    Set BlankCells = .Resize(RowSize:=.Rows.Count - 1).Offset(RowOffset:=1).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks)
End With
On Error GoTo 0

If Not BlankCells Is Nothing Then
    BlankCells.Delete Shift:=xlUp
End If
```

Comment: thank you very much but an error is appearing while initiating the code on this line `BlankCells.Delete Shift:=xlUp` that is `Delete mehod of Range class failed`

Comment: @Valiant can you include some example data where this happens in your original question? Because in my test this worked.

Comment: I have updated a picture if it does not help i will upload a Test sheet.

Comment: Try to change `BlankCells.Delete Shift:=xlUp` into `BlankCells.Select` so you see what it would delete. And check if this looks good or somehow wrong.

Comment: [Download Sheet](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1VEwOd0xZS8mJdMfEwfvbqYIh_sM0BNww/view?usp=sharing) Let me Explain it one more time. My above code is deleting all the Table Rows by the value/string of `Coulmn1`. I have been using a Code which paste the data in Column1 which adds more rows to the `Table3` and when data is less in Column1 then  my code deletes the empty rows of the table. But when whole Column1 is empty it deletes all the rows then my formula has also been deleted.

Comment: I cannot reproduce your issue. I run the code and it deleted every line below Order No. 230. Worked with the code you wrote in Module2 without error.

Comment: Yes that is great thing But when whole column1 is empty then what would be the code output. Your code will delete all rows below `Order_No.`?

Comment: No it deletes all empty rows below the header `Order_No.` **exept** the first data row. So speaking in row numbers of the sheet: Your table starts with the header  `Order_No.` in row 2. It will never delete row 3 no matter if empty or not, but it will delete all empty rows below row 3.

Comment: Thank you very very much @Pᴇʜ i have been looking this for so long Thank you.

Comment: @Valiant I just saw in your code in the file you uploaded you changed it to `RowOffset:=3`. **That is wrong** it needs to be `RowOffset:=1` don't change that!

Comment: Yes i changed it but also before it was not working but now when i test it again its working Thank you so much for being so nice